# Sort Perl hash from largest to smallest

Tags: perl, hash, perl-hash

I am looking at an example found here: http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/sort_function.html

And it gives this code to sort a hash based on each key's value:

```
# Using <=> instead of cmp because of the numbers
    foreach my $fruit (sort {$data{$a} <=> $data{$b}} keys %data) {
        print $fruit . ": " . $data{$fruit} . "\n";
    }
```

This code I do not fully understand, but when I experiment with it, it sorts from lowest to highest. How can I flip it to sort from highest to lowest?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Swap `$a` and `$b`:

```
foreach my $fruit (sort {$data{$b} <=> $data{$a}} keys %data) {
```

Answer (score 16):

Just use `reverse sort` instead of `sort`.

`foreach my $fruit (reverse sort keys %data) { ...`

Comment: That works, but sorting and then reversing the list is less efficient than just swapping the sense of the comparison in the first place.

Comment: @MarkReed: This seems to claim `reverse` is not less efficient: http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/Perl-Critic-1.117/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/BuiltinFunctions/ProhibitReverseSortBlock.pm

Comment: @MarkReed: `reverse` is more efficient and more readable code.

Comment: @toolic: Interesting, did not know that. I wonder if the optimization extends to comparing `$data{$a}` and `$data{$b}`, instead of just `$a` and `$b`.